# Добавление данных в форму

Tags: python, django

Есть модель:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='Anonymous')
    date = models.DateTimeField()
```

Есть форма модели:

```
class PostForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Post
        fields = ['title', 'author', 'text']
```

Дата на форме не выводится. Как сделать, чтобы дата добавлялась при отправке формы?

Comment: Добавьте date в fields. Или я что то не так понял?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При сохранении формы во view делаете следующее:

```
from django.utils import timezone # если нужно
# ... 
form = PostForm(request.POST)
# ... 
if form.is_valid():
    my_post = form.save(commit=False) # получаем модель, не сохраненную в базу
    my_post.date = timezone.now() # записываем нужную дату, например, timezone.now()
    my_post.save()
```

По умолчанию у метода save() commit=True, т.е. происходит сохранение в базу данных. Здесь же мы сначала получаем объект (используя commit=False), модифицируем его, как нам надо (задаем нужную дату) и сохраняем в базу.

Есть и другие решения - например, переопределить метод save или использовать скрытое поле, но этот более явный и простой.

Comment: А насколько правильный шаг добавить в DateTimeField параметр auto_now_add=True?

Comment: Нормальный шаг. Но учтите, что если Вы добавляете auto_now = True или auto_now_add = True, то это поле становится предназначено для автоматического изменения данных, но Вы не сможете вывести его потом где-то в форме для изменения (или изменить в админке).